# How to return some column items in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want print some items in `2D` `NumPy` array.

For example:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]

a = numpy.array(a)
```

My questions:

1. How can I return just `(1 and 2)`? As well as `(5 and 6)`?
2. And how can I keep the dimension as `[2, 2]`

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
a[:, [0, 1]]
```

will select only the first two columns (with index 0 and 1). The result will be:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: thank you, but,what should I do if there is a lot of columns such as 100 and I just want return first 51?

Comment: Like the other answers: `a[, :51]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing to get necessary parts of the numpy array.
To get 1 and 2 you need to select 0's row and the first two columns, i.e.

```
>>> a[0, 0:2]
array([1, 2])
```

Similarly for 5 and 6

```
>>> a[1, 0:2]
array([5, 6])
```

You can also select a 2x2 subarray, e.g.

```
>>> a[:,0:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
In [44]: a[:, :2]
Out[44]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```